# $\{ (x,x) ∣ x \in B\}$ is measurable if and only if $B$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

How to prove the following

> If $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ then $\{ (x,x) ∣ x \in B\}$ is Borel measurable if and only if $B$ is Borel measurable

Specifically how do you prove the implication, if $\{ (x,x) ∣ x \in B\}$ is measurable then $B$ is measurable?

Comment: Is $B\subset{\Bbb R}$.

Comment: Yes. Sorry my mistake.

Comment: And with the Lebesgue measure...

Comment: Sorry again. Wrt Borel sigma-algebra

Comment: Add "Borel measurable."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diagonal $D=\{(x,x):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is measurable, since it is closed. The set $B\times\mathbb{R}$ is measurable, since the projection $\pi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ onto the first coordinate is continuous and hence measurable and $B\times\mathbb{R}$ is $\pi^{-1}(B)$. Now the desired set is $D\cap B\times\mathbb{R}$ and hence measurable..

Comment: That shows the implication, if $B$ is measurable then $\{ (x,x) ∣ x \in B \}$ is measurable, doesn't it? 
How to prove the other side?

Comment: @Guest_000 The function $x\mapsto (x,x)$ is continuous and hence measurable.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: this is the answer for the Lebesgue-measurable case.

Is true? Let $B$ nonmeasurable. $\{(x,x) ∣ x\in B\}\subset\{(x,x) ∣ x\in {\Bbb R}\}$, a set of measure zero.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra